# Aggregate function to sum values from multiple rows into one result row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

it's been some years since I used the Oracle SQL pivot function and I cannot quite get mine to work for this short example.

I would like to transform the multiple columns/ rows from this table

```
ID   CLASS   NAME   WHEIGHT
1    2020    Tom    80
2    2020    Tim    100
3    2020    Ben    120
```

into this single result row:

```
CLASS    LISTAGG_NAMES    SUM_WHEIGHT
2020     Tom,Tim,Ben      300
```

Thank you very much for some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "pivot" problem.  You do not want separate columns for each value.  You just want to concatenate them.  Use `listagg()`:

```
select class, listagg(name, ',') within group (order by weight) as names, sum(weight)
from t
group by class;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that did the trick. I also changed the question title